When I created the group in the ios background and added it, xcode said it was unavailable
After the ios background creates the group and adds it to the Identifiers, an error is displayed at xcode signing. Error: An Application group with Identifier 'group.xx' is not available. Please enter a different string.
Looking at Figure 1 and Figure 2, you can see that I have created in the background, but it will not succeed in Xcode. Does anyone know the reason?
I started to think that the account and certificate problems, but after the replacement is not successful




The group name is in use by another developer team than the one you have selected in your code signing section. Verify your developer team is correct or use a different group name

I believe that the key for the app group identifiers “must consist of your development team ID, followed by a period, followed by an arbitrary name chosen by your development team.” See “Adding an App to an App Group” in Entitlement Key Reference.
